# C# - Access select query using Date/Time

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datetime, subquery

So I'm making a database for a school project regarding Movies / Actors (2 different tables).
In the Microsoft Access database one of the field's type is Date/Time and I want to create a select query that will return me all movies from the year given for example:

> public static DataSet GetByYear(string actorYear)

It needs to like something like this:

> string sQuery = SELECT * FROM ActorsTable WHERE ActorsTable.actorDate.Year = actorYear

Something like that +-
Also, can anyone please show me how can I make a select that will return me all actors (select * from ...) but sorted by their age?

Comment: For people voting to close, this may not be the best question, but it is not terrible and the user is very new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query based on the year of a date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ActorsTable 
WHERE YEAR(actorDate) = actorYear
```

Actors ordered by age:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT a.*, DateDiff('yyyy', a.ActorDate, Now()) + 
              Int(Format(Now(), 'mmdd') < Format(a.ActorDate, 'mmdd')) 
              AS AgeOfActor
  FROM ActorsTable AS a
) AS m
ORDER BY m.AgeOfActor
```

Comment: how can I check the age?
Will "ORDER BY Year(actorDate)" work?

Comment: ***@user3376059***, I have modified my answer to show you how to get their actual age and then sort on it youngest to oldest.